# making a paragraph in html contain a text from a file

Tags: html

I have an html paragraph (inside a div) in which I want to display a simple fixed text. The text is a bit long so I'd rather the text will be in a seperate txt file.
something like

```
<div><p txt=file.txt></p></div>
```

Can I do something like that?

Comment: The engine won't parse them if you preface your line of code with 4 consecutive spaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You should format your code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: HTML can include img, but can't include txt... <facepalm>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be done with HTML `<embed>` or `<object>` tags, Javascript, or PHP/ASP/other back-end languages.

**PHP (as example of server-side language) is the the way I've always done it:**

```
<div><p><?php include('myFile.txt'); ?></p></div>
```

---

To use this (if you're unfamiliar with PHP), you can:

**1)** [check if you have php on your server](http://support.dominion-web.com/response/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=25)

**2)** change the file extension of your .html file to .php

**3)** paste the code from my PHP example somewhere in the body of your newly-renamed PHP file

Comment: Or with SSI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes ... but this is not much seen today.

Comment: @leonbloy - Interesting - never even heard of that before! :)

Comment: well, It's the correct way - a bit hectic because of the same-sever-policy of js. In my case I'd have to create a special php code in the server

Comment: What nonsense. Of course you can do this with HTML. Use the `<embed>` or `<object>` tags.

Answer (score 45):

You can do something like that in pure html using an `<object>` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object):
`<div><object data="file.txt"></object></div>`

This method has some limitations though, like, it won't fit size of the block to the content - you have to specify `width` and `height` manually. And styles won't be applied to the text.

Comment: is possible do this 1) without actually showing this on web page and 2) pass the content into javascript (I just want to pass some text to javascript without using any web server and sophisticated things like jQuerry, or other stuff)

Comment: @prokop-hapala sadly it is not possible to pass file on local machine to javascript for [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). You need a web server for that.

Answer (score 18):

You can use a simple HTML element `<embed src="file.txt">` it loads the external resource and displays it on the screen no js needed

Comment: Similarly, you could also embed an html file.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript will do the trick here.

```
function load() {
    var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
    file.open("GET", "http://remote.tld/random.txt", true);
    file.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (file.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse
        if (file.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file
          text = file.responseText;
          document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = text;
        }
      }
    }
}

window.onLoad = load();
```

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587998, I needed to register the onreadystatechange callback before calling open().  I also needed `file.send();`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use javascript for this.

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "http://my.remote.url/myremotefile.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.readyState === 4 && txtFile.status == 200) {
     allText = txtFile.responseText;
  }
document.getElementById('your div id').innerHTML = allText;
```

This is just a code sample, would need tweaking for all browsers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a javascript code I have tested successfully :

```
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var allText = "file not found";
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (txtFile.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && txtFile.status == 200) {
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
            allText = allText.split("\n").join("<br>");
        }

        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = allText;
    }
    txtFile.open("GET", '/result/client.txt', true);
    txtFile.send(null);
```