# Images can be pulled externally from a source <img src="..." />. Can TEXT be pulled externally without javascript? <span src="...">

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can source an image externally from a URL.

`<img src="http://www.sourcefile.com/image.jpg" />`

Is there a way to externally source text from a URL without needing Javascript?

**Example:**

`<a href="http://www.sourcefile.com/myname.txt"></a>`

Will appear as

`Jon`

...because that's the text inside of the referenced text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making a paragraph in html contain a text from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348207/making-a-paragraph-in-html-contain-a-text-from-a-file)

Comment: `<iframe>`? `<object>`?

Answer (score 0):

without javascript, you cant do it. but its possible to use iframe to load some external page content.