# Reading content from .txt file into a paragraph tag <p></p>

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to read the content from the .txt file and display the content at the paragraph tag

on the client side. I absolutely got no idea how can i do that and i do not any function that i use. Please, advice me on this. I looked at this but anything seems to meet my requirements [making a paragraph in html contain a text from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348207/making-a-paragraph-in-html-contain-a-text-from-a-file)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        String line;
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Test.txt";
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                //write the lie to console window
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //Read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the file
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e1.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you're included ASP.NET tag, you can use `WebMethod` and return contents of text file as a string. Then, in your AJAX call, use `$('#target').text(contents)` to display the content (assumed you have paragraph tag like `<p id="target"></p>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a p tag as runat="server" on your aspx page like this

```
<p runat="server" id="paragraph"></p>
```

Then in your code behind (aspx.vb file) after reading all your lines do this:

```
paragraph.InnerText = "Your variable containing the text";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<p runat="server" id="para" />`
And in your code behind, use this id `para` and set its text like this

```
para.InnerHtml = "sample text to be set"
```