# Insert a Separate txt file into a <p> tag without js ONLY html

Tags: html, tags

I have an html paragraph (inside a div) in which I want to display a simple fixed text. The text is a bit long so I'd rather the text will be in a seperate txt file.
something like this. (WITHOUT JS ONLY HTML)

```
<div><p txt=file.txt></p></div>
```

Comment: This is almost a copy paste of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348207/14316282) so you should clarify the difference is you don't want it with JS. However, the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242521/14316282) answers that too.

Comment: @RolvApneseth: Yea but is there another way, because i want to style the text

Comment: I think if you want styling it's only possible the 2 ways the accepted answer on that question suggests